# Would using covariant return type in clone really break compatibility?

Tags: java

I've recently encountered [Why doesn't Java 5+ API take advantage of covariant return types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751160/why-doesnt-java-5-api-take-advantage-of-covariant-return-types).

I agree with the Question, in Java 5 JDK developers could have used covariant return type for clone and changed existing classes so we could write

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> clone = list.clone();
```

instead of

```
ArrayList<String> clone = (ArrayList<String>)list.clone();
```

but by some reasons the did not do that.

I've done some experiments changing my `test.ArrayList.clone` return type from Object to  ArrayList to see if "Previously compiled classes cannot find the method with the new return type" but could not reproduce the problem. In the bytecode, a call to old `test.ArrayList.clone` looks like

```
 INVOKEVIRTUAL test.ArrayList.clone()Ljava/lang/Object;
```

that is, the method signature contains return type, so after my change its signature changes to `test.ArrayList.clone()Ltest.ArrayList`. So it seems that old class will break, but in fact it doesn't because there are 2 clone methods in test.ArrayList.class

```
  public clone()Ltest.ArrayList;
  public bridge clone()Ljava/lang/Object;
```

the second one is a bridge, all it does is calling the covariant version

```
 ...
 INVOKEVIRTUAL ArrayList.clone()Ltest.ArrayList;
 ...
```

so old classes continue working with no problem.

Can anyone explain how changing clone's return type can break the bytecode?

Comment: As far as I understand, it is because of type erasure: at run time, `ArrayList<X>` becomes `ArrayList` for whatever `X`. It is for compatibility with pre-1.5 code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3751291/396730) to the linked question does contain the reason: it would break all subclasses of `ArrayList` that overwrote the `clone` method and specified `Object` as return type.