# Why standard java classes's clone() return Object instead of actual type

Tags: java

It's allowed in java to specify type of function return, for example following code

```
public class Test {

    static class Dad {
        Dad me() {
            return this;
        }
    }

    static class Son extends Dad {
        Son me() {
            return this;
        }
    }
 }
```

is valid.

Let's see `ArrayList` class. It has overridden `clone()` function (At least I see it in Oracle jdk 1.7 source)

```
public Object clone() {
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ArrayList<E> v = (ArrayList<E>) super.clone();
        v.elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
        v.modCount = 0;
        return v;
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        // this shouldn't happen, since we are Cloneable
        throw new InternalError();
    }
}
```

What's the point not to return `ArrayList<E>` but just `Object` ?

Comment: You can write a copy method.  You're not limited to clone.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Backwards compatibility.

Prior to Java 5, the return type could not be narrowed when overriding, so `ArrayList.clone()` was declared to return `Object`. Now that the language permits that, they can't use it, because narrowing the return type of `ArrayList.clone()` would break existing subclasses of ArrayList that override `ArrayList.clone()` with return type `Object`.

Comment: They can, if the existing subclasses are also changed

Comment: As if no java update ever has been backwards-incompatible....

Answer (score 11):

One reason is backwards compatibility.  The signature of the `Object.clone()` method was specified way back in Java 1.0, when there wasn't support for covariant return types.  If they changed this fundamental method as you suggested, it could break thousands of legacy programs where the `clone()` method might not return an object with the same type as `this`.

See also:

- [Would using covariant return type in clone really break compatibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021601/would-using-covariant-return-type-in-clone-really-break-compatibility)
- [Why doesn't Java 5+ API take advantage of covariant return types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751160/why-doesnt-java-5-api-take-advantage-of-covariant-return-types)